# Sequence with a property in the numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations

Suppose I had a sequence $\{s_n\}$ defined in the following way:

- $s_1=s_2=1$

And for $i \geq 3,$

- $s_i=s_{i-1}+s_{i-2}$ if $i$ is odd
- $\frac{1}{s_i}=\frac{1}{s_{i-1}}+\frac{1}{s_{i-2}}$ if $i$ is even.

Prove that for all terms in the sequence $\{s_n\}$, the numerator is a power of 2.

After writing out the first few terms of $\{s_n\}$, one can conjecture that the numerator for $s_{2i}$ and $s_{2i-1}$ is the same. Moreover, the denominator of $s_{2i}$ seems to be a multiple of the denominator of $s_{2i-1}$. I'm guessing that some sort of induction may help, though I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: isn't $s_3=2$ (=even)?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote part of the question wrong. It should read "the numerator is a power of 2". It is fixed, and again I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you guys know that this is part of an ongoing competition: https://www.nicecontest.xyz/; the only difference was that the sequence (a_n) was changed to (s_n).  This isn't even a prestigious contest, so what's the point of cheating on it?

Answer (score 1):

The first few terms of this sequence are $1, 1, 2, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{8}{3}, \frac{8}{15}, \frac{16}{5}, \frac{16}{35}$. Looking at these, we see a pattern: if $i$ is odd, $s_{i + 1} = \frac{s_{i}}{i}$, and if $i$ is even, $s_{i + 1} = i*s_i$. We can prove this with induction; I won't go through the whole proof, but note that $s_{i} + s_{i + 1} = s_{i} + \frac{s_i}{i} = \frac{(i + 1)s_{i}}{i}$ when $i$ is odd and $\frac{1}{s_{i}} + \frac{1}{s_{i + 1}} = \frac{1}{s_{i}} + \frac{1}{i*s_{i}} = \frac{i + 1}{i*s_{i}}$ when $i$ is even. These can be used to complete the inductive step.

This means that $s_{i}$ is the product of all the even terms less than or equal to $i$ divided by the product of all the odd terms less than or equal to $i$. Written out, this is $\frac{2*4*...* (2\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor)}{1*3*...*(2\left \lfloor{\frac{i + 1}{2}}\right \rfloor - 1)} = \frac{({2*4*...* (2\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor)})^2}{i!} = \frac{2^{2\left \lfloor{i/2} \right \rfloor} (\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}} \right \rfloor !)^2}{i!}$.

For any odd prime $p$ and positive integer $x$, the amount of factors of $p$ in $x!$ is $\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{p}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{p^2}}\right \rfloor + ...$. Note that $2\left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{\frac{i}{p^k}}\right \rfloor$, so every odd prime appears at least as many times in the denominator as in the numerator, and a power of two remains in the numerator. Hope this helps!

Edit: Here's a quick proof that $2\left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{\frac{i}{p^k}}\right \rfloor$. $ 2\left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{\frac{2\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{2\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor = \left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{i}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor$. The reason why $2\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{2x}\right \rfloor$ is because $2\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$ is an integer less than or equal to $2x$.

Comment: How do you prove that $2\left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{i}{2}}\right \rfloor}{p^k}}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{\frac{i}{p^k}}\right \rfloor$?